# Largest possible variance for log-concave distributions on a bounded interval

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, probability-distributions, convexity

Let $f$ be the density of a log-concave probability distribution on the interval $[0,1]$ (with respect to Lebesgue measure). To be concrete, suppose that $f(x) = \exp( - \varphi(x))$, for some convex function $\varphi: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$.

Is it true that the largest variance of a random variable with density $f$, is attained by the uniform density? (that is, the largest variance is $\frac{1}{12}$). If it is true, is there a simple proof?

If the density is only required to be unimodal, then the supremum over the variance is $\frac19$ (the proof [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142651/does-the-uniform-distribution-have-the-greatest-variance-among-all-concave-distr?noredirect=1&lq=1) is wrong). In case the density itself is concave, there is a proof [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0893965907000353/1-s2.0-S0893965907000353-main.pdf?_tid=83d2b574-6861-11e6-b0c5-00000aab0f26&acdnat=1471868051_76d081edd1bf1d24c05d4ebe14f2369d).

Comment: What is the mistake in the CrossValidated proof?

Comment: The maximum of the expression $\frac13 \mu (2 - 3 \mu)$ over the interval $0 \le \mu \le \frac12$ is $\frac19$ and not $\frac{1}{12}$.